# Does JQuery have inheritance built into it?

Tags: jquery

Does JQuery have built-in inheritance like prototype?

Just found this Question: [JQuery inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075660/jquery-class-inheritance)

My original search criteria failed, and I guess from moderation a stupid question...

Comment: Into what piece of programming software?

Comment: Please be a little more specific. Also have you performed any research into this yourself?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `built-in inheritance` and `prototype`?

Comment: Did you mean a plug-in, which helps you create inheritance?

Comment: Javascript has prototypical inheritance built in.

Comment: First line, first sentence: "For OO, it's best to look outside jQuery."

Comment: @jholloman, prototypal inheritance is not actually built in Javascript. You need [a small, but quite well-known function](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you get down-voted into oblivion, I will tell you. No it does not, since Javascript does not support a class structure, this type of paradigm does not exist in JQuery. There are plugins for it. Good luck.

Comment: Just because there is no class structure in Javascript doesn't mean that Objects cannot inherit from each other.